# Are OpenGL textures' resolutions automatically scaled down?

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, textures

What I mean, if I want to use a bitmap for a texture, should I make sure that this bitmap is as small as possible in order to save memory from the textures ? (Ofcourse I throw away the Bitmap itself after the texture has been created). Or can I just use a 512x512 bmp and OpenGL automatically makes a texture based on a smaller size (since it's just going to be a ball in a breakout game) ?

Since I could imagine it takes loads of time figuring out the perfect size of a bitmap if it's going to be used at multiple resolutions, from ldpi phones to tablets (Android...).  Or must I create different sized images for the same image, like 512,256,128 . . . ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An OpenGL texture is as large as you create it to be (using `glTexImage2D`, for example). If you want to create a texture from a bitmap, you either make the texture as large as the bitmap or scale the bitmap data down somehow yourself. How should OpenGL automatically know the best texture size for your application, let aside scaling it down for you, which is of course your job.

If you are really talking about automatic mipmap generation, then this is possible and you should look at Salvatore's answer. But if you really speak of OpenGL choosing the "best" size for your texture and initializing its data using a completely different sized image, no that's definitely not possible.

Comment: Ok, openGL automatically resizing was kinda stupid of me, but mipmapping isn't really what i'm looking for, since it's a 2D-only game. I'm going for a scaled-down bmp now.

Comment: Well, if a fitting answer isn't there, what should I do?

Comment: @user717572 You may just leave the question un-accepted. I know it sounds a bit self-interested, but I actually answered your question correctly. You wanted to know if OpenGL can automatically scale down a bitmap to use as texture and I gave the correct answer (No it can't), if you like this answer or not. Or do you have some unclarities regarding the answer? Then feel free to ask about them.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about mip-map generation? http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/mipmap_generation.html

This page gives you a generic example on how to generate mipmaps in a computer application, using glu library. I really don't know much about android (still) but of course opengl will not use mip maps if you don't tell opengl to do that.
Having mipmaps increases both performances and rendering quality.
In ram mipmaps of 512x512 pixel images don't get much memory.
You'll load the same image at 512x512, 256x256, 128x128, 64x64, 32x32, 16x16, 8x8, 4x4, 1x1 using the maximum number of levels, but you can choose to save just the first 3 or 4 levels. Since the amount of ram decrease exponentially the more level you add, the higher levels will consume literaly only some bytes of memory.

See also this question http://www.gamedev.net/topic/611182-android-and-mipmaps/